# Adding assemblies to catalog using MEF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, mef

Have a rather large project with nearly a dozen assemblies added to the shell and other assemblies added via config

Trying to find a better way to add assemblies referenced in the project

The code so far looks like this

```
 Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>(); // to avoid duplicate parts
 foreach (Assembly an in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            addAssembly(an, dict);

 foreach (AssemblyName an in Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies())
            addAssembly(an, dict);

 foreach (AssemblyName an in GetAsmInConfig())
            addAssembly(an, dict);
```

Even so, not all assemblies referenced at design time to Shell are added to the catalog

Wondering if there's anything short of adding all assemblies to config that will do the trick

UPDATE

```
  void addAssembly(Assembly a, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        if (a.IsDynamic || dict.ContainsKey(a.FullName))
            return;

        dict.Add(a.FullName, a.FullName);
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(a));        
    }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have some assemblies defined in a config file that contains parts for MEF and others referenced in a project that also contain parts for MEF. You are trying to build a catalog for your CompositionContainer so that all parts from both sources are included. Currently some parts don't end end in your catalog. Do you need to look for parts in more than one assembly ?

Comment: What does the addAssembly method do exactly? Could you post the code?

Comment: I'm trying to AddParts to catalog which are referenced at design time without adding them explicitly in code and then add additional parts based on config file and using the dictionary to avoid duplicates an issue i ran into a while back and spent a couple of days debugging !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the compiler will remove refferences to that are not actually used so you can not rely on this as a mechanism to enumerate assemblies. 
Your options are to:

1. use a config file
2. use a directory catalog

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you are trying to get all assemblies (from appdomain, referenced by entry assembly and in a config file) in a dictionary and then supply this to MEF so that it looks for parts in those assemblies.

Instead of using this I would supply my CompositionContainer with an AggregateCatalog. Then I would create DirectoryCatalogs and supply the folder where said assemblies (dll) reside.

These could be the bin folder of the project which should already contain most dlls, plus any other folders you need (the ones where the assemblies currently specified in your config file reside).

Even better, I would create a /plugin or /parts directory in my bin folder. With post-build events (in project properties) I would copy all the dlls I need for parts which aren't already in my bin folder. Then I would do something like this:

```
var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();

var mainDirectoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(".");
var partsDirectoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog("./parts");

aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(mainDirectoryCatalog);
aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(partsDirectoryCatalog);
```

If you supply this aggregateCatalog to your CompositionContainer, all dlls from both of those directories will be scanned for parts. Since the entry assembly and it's referenced assemblies is already in the bin it would get those. The rest of the assemblies would be copied in the parts directory.

Comment: that's certainly doable but i cannot use DirectoryCatalog, that's 1 reason why i have the dictionary in code to avoid duplicates

Comment: why can't you use `DirectoryCatalog`?

Comment: @jberger long story but in short the parts and versions are centrally managed, that's why